# Shiny Server Error - could not find function "renderplot"

Tags: shiny, chord

I am new to Shiny and am trying to add a chord diagram to a shiny server. When I hit the runApp button in RStudio I get the application to run and it generates the UI, but then closes down immediately and I get the following error in the RConsole window: Error in (structure(function (input, output)  : 
  could not find function "renderplot".

Unfortunately, I cannot attach the data as it is proprietary, but I am just creating an adjacency matrix in order to generate the chord plot. The Chord plot works fine outside Shiny. Thanks in advance!

My UI and Server code is below:

```
library(shiny)

# Starting line
shinyUI(fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("Chord Chart"),

  # Sidebar
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      #Data selection for Chord Chart
      selectInput("data","Select a Dataset:",
                  c("Marine"))),

    #The plot created in server.R is displayed
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("plot")
)))
)

library(circlize)
library(dplyr)
library(reshape2)
library(manipulate)
library(shiny)


# read marine summaries
marine <- readfile("C:/Personal/R/MarineDataSummary.csv")

# group and summarize by O-D
marine.sum <- marine %>%group_by(Handling_Port, OD_Port_Country) %>%
  summarise(tons <-sum(tonnes))    # prepare pivot table
marine.sum1 <- acast(marine.sum, Handling_Port~OD_Port_Country, value.tons="z")    # reshape matrix
marine.sum1[is.na(marine.sum1)] <- 0    # set NA to zero

#initialization of server.R
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  output$plot <- renderplot({
    c <- chordDiagram(marine.sum1,annotationTrack="grid",preAllocateTracks=list(track.height = 0.3))
    ##change axis
    c <- c + circos.trackPlotRegion(track.index=1, panel.fun=function(x,y) {
      xlim = get.cell.meta.data("xlim") 
      ylim = get.cell.meta.data("ylim")
      sector.name=get.cell.meta.data("sector.index")
      circos.text(mean(xlim), ylim[1], sector.name,facing="clockwise",
                  niceFacing=TRUE,adj=c(0,0.4), cex = 0.4)},bg.border=NA)
    print(c)

  })
})
```

Comment: It's `renderPlot`, not `renderplot`.  Capital "P".  You'll avoid such easy mistakes by using tab-autocomplete in RStudio

Comment: Awesome! much appreciated. I learnt today, once again that the "devil lies in the detail". will use auto .complete henceforth